# Dropzone is not defined, with webpack on symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, dropzone

I watched the various conversations on the subject, sorry to redo a topic but I look for a whole day and I do not understand why Dropzone is not defined.

In my console it's always the same speech ...
***Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined***

Where could I have been wrong?

```
<div action="{{path('document_create')}}" class="dropzone">
       <div class="fallback">
              {{ form_widget(form.file, {
                  'attr': {'type': 'file', 'name': 'file'}
              }) }}
       </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

                $(function() {
                    //Dropzone class
                    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
                        url: "upload.php",
                        paramName: "file",
                        maxFilesize: 2,
                        maxFiles: 10,
                        acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf"
                    });

                    $('#startUpload').click(function(){           
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post the solution I just found after a battle on symfony and webpack!

The trick: (for Symfony and webpack)

1 / Install dropzone

2 / Leave the file dropzone.js or dropzone.min.js in the node_modules, do not touch them.

3 / Create a file.js, ex: myDropzone.js

4 / Call Dropzone in myDropzone.js with:

```
window.Dropzone = require('dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min');
```

5 / As well as the dropzone config code according to your choices:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  $(function() {
      //Dropzone class
        $('.dropzone').dropzone({
          paramName: "file",
          maxFilesize: 2,
          maxFiles: 2,
          addRemoveLinks: true,
          acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf"
      });
  });
```